# OnAuthorization isn't being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I use a WebApi Service with custom Authorization. This is the AuthorizationAttribute: (to keep it as simple as possible I removed all logic and just try to send a 401):

```
public class Auth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private readonly List<Permissions> _requiredPermissions;

    public Auth(params Permissions[] permissions)
    {
      _requiredPermissions = permissions.ToList();
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); 
    }
}
```

Inside my Controller-Actions I call the Auth the following way:

```
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
   [Auth(Permissions.CanLogin, Permissions.IsAdmin)]
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
   {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

(`Permissions` is just a simple enum.)

I can see that the constructor from `Auth()` is called at program start. But the "`OnAuthorization()`" method never gets called.

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the authorization I implemented was from MVC. But for web api, another authorization is needed, which looks nearly the same but differs a bit.

First I had to remove the reference to MVC in the custom authorization class and use web.http instead:

So. I had to remove this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc
```

and instead add this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

Then the OnAuthorization-Method needs another Parameter.
So I had to change this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

to this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
```

(HttpActionContext is inside the System.Web.Http.Controllers - namespace)

It seems the authorizaton stopped working after I installed the most current version of WebApi using the nuget-console inside a "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" with Web Api Options enabled.